# GWT. How to change flex table's column width?

Tags: gwt, width, flextable

I can't change width of first column with CheckBoxes in my FlexTable.
[image: first column is very wide]

I tried to use

```
filterGrid.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(0, "15px");
```

but it hadn't any effect.

Please suggest me something.

Appendix 1.

```
<table class="content" aria-hidden="false">
<colgroup><col width="10px"></col></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span class="gwt-CheckBox" style="width: 1em;">
<input id="gwt-uid-9" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0"></input>
<label for="gwt-uid-9"></label></span>
</td>
```

Comment: try `filterGrid.getFlexCellFormatter().setWidth(row, column, width)`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Try `FlexTable.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(column, width);`

For example, I just tried `table.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(0, "400px");`

and that generated the following HTML:

```
<colgroup>
    <col width="400px">
</colgroup>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately setting table.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(0, "400px"); doesn't effect on table. As in your html colgroup changes, but as I said it has no effect.

Comment: If it had no effect, there may be another CSS style affecting your table. If you have a `<table class='...'>` attribute, try removing the CSS classes you have assigned and see if it makes a difference. Otherwise,  when you inspect your HTML on the browser, the right column of the inspect window will show what CSS styles are affecting your table. Check if anything is affecting that `<td>` tag as well.

Comment: As you had suggested, I inspected my HTML. There were a few CSS styles, but they weren't refer to size. I added Appendix 1 in my question part. There is you can see the structure of the table with checkboxes. And size of that TD cell doesn't change.

Comment: Can you try removing the `style="width: 1em;"` from the `<span>` element of your Appendix 1? I think it is stretching out your `<td>`

Comment: I removed `style`, but it didn't help. As I see the problem is in `<td>` element. Thank you very much that you try to help me.